# In what scenarios does the I2C Master pull the SCL line low?

Tags: embedded, protocols, i2c, soc

I have a board which acts as the I2C master. There is only one master. It is connected to two slaves. One slave supports clock stretching while the other does not. Between a read or write transaction, the line is pulled low. Is it possible that the slave will not pull the line low?

Comment: We need more context. Please show us some wave forms, you can draw them with any graphic program, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Frome [Wikipedia, Physical layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) paragraph :

> While SCL is low, the transmitter (initially the master) sets SDA to
>   the desired value and (after a small delay to let the value propagate)
>   lets SCL float high. The master then waits for SCL to actually go
>   high; this will be delayed by the finite rise time of the SCL signal
>   (the RC time constant of the pull-up resistor and the parasitic
>   capacitance of the bus) and may be additionally delayed by a slave's
>   clock stretching. Once SCL is high, the master waits a minimum time (4 μs for 
>   standard-speed I²C) to ensure that the receiver has seen the bit, then
>   pulls it low again. This completes transmission of one bit.

So yes the master can pull the SCL line low. It's a normal end of transmission.